# babel, browserify error : using removed babel 5 option base.stage

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, babeljs

I am getting this error when I run `grunt browserify`

> ReferenceError: [BABEL] src/app.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.stage - Check out the corresponding stage-x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets while parsing file: src/app.js

This is my gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    browserify: {
        main: {
          options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
              debug: true
            },
            transform: [["babelify", { "stage": 1 }]]
          },
          src: 'src/app.js',
          dest: 'scripts/app.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: [ 'src/**/*.js' ],
      tasks: ['browserify'],
      options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
    },
    connect: {
      target:{
            options: {
                port: 9001
            }
        }
    },
    bower: {
        flat: { /* flat folder/file structure */
            dest: 'scripts',
            options: {
                debugging: true
            }
        }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('main-bower-files');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'bower', 'connect', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', [ 'clean', 'bower', 'copy', 'uglify' ]);

};
```

And this is my babelrc

```
  {
    "presets": ["stage-1","es2015"]
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please add link to the project/files or publish content here. I have lots of experience with this and am able to solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking a look!

https://github.com/lukasoktaba/run-test

Comment: The project works when you clone it.. what is the change you're trying to do that causes the issue?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/407) you might be importing the entire repository instead of a specific file.

Comment: It's when I save app.js in src. It won't copy to scripts.

Comment: I took out 'node-modules' from bower.json. getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158238/discussion-between-guy-mograbi-and-user3943543).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the grunt definition for babelify is obsolete and invalid.

It does not accept an option named `stage` anymore.

I would try

```
 browserify: {
        main: {
          options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
              debug: true
            },
            transform: [["babelify",  {presets: ["stage-1", "es2015"]}]]
          },
          src: 'src/app.js',
          dest: 'scripts/app.js'
        }
    },
```

replace `{stage: 1}` with `{presets: ... }`

Or - since you have this defined in `.babelrc`, you might be able to remove it altogether. I assume babelify applies those configurations.